# radio button of a class clicked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following radio button in my page

```
<input type="radio" name="launch_selection" class="linkToSectionSurvey expandSectionSurvey" id="linkTosectionSurvey1" rel="Surveysection1">

<input type="radio" name="launch_selection" id="all_active_members" class="linkToSectionSurvey expandSectionSurvey">
```

And this the code in my js file, which I am using for radio button click event.

```
jQuery('input[type=radio].expandSectionSurvey').live('click',function(e){

});
```

My requirement is to check the class clicked.

Jquery function is getting called on radio button clicked.

Only issue is its not showing "checked" even after it is clicked.

Its an old application using jquery version 1.4.2, which I cannot upgrade because at almost all places ".live" is used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use **change** event. `$(this).attr('class')` to get classnames, `$(this).hasClass('someClass')` to check if element has a class

Comment: `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. Please convert to `.on()`.

Comment: Show the code you're using to check if the button is clicked.

Comment: @Barmar OP might be using older version of jQuery, but good point if not

Comment: I tried changing the jquery code to "('input[type=radio].expandSectionSurvey').on('click',function(e)", but its saying "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this comment says everything:
*`.live()` was deprecated in jQuery `1.7`, removed in `1.9`. Please convert to `.on()`*

So, Only if your radio elements are dynamically generated/created only in this case you should follow the `event delegation` event binding. you have to convert it with `.on()` event listener in conjunction with `change` event:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('expandSectionSurvey')){
        // do something
    }else{
        // do something else
    }
});
```

---

As per comment jquery v1.4.x:

```
jQuery('input[type=radio]').live('change', function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('expandSectionSurvey')){
        // do something
    }else{
        // do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer, but its an old application using version "v1.4.2".I cannot upgrade it because at almost places .live is used

Comment: okay then you can use the same with live along with change event.

Comment: this worked like a charm for me, just a heads up for them who downgraded the question without any information.

Answer (score 0):

Add this flie as reference: or use old one

> > type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"

Use this, it may be helpful

```
$('input[type=radio].expandSectionSurvey').live('click',function(e){
alert('Test')
});
```

.live()

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
```

.on()

```
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Its saying ".on is not a function" is not a function.i am using version v1.4.2

Comment: Can you replace your jquery file version  ?

Comment: thankyou for the answer, but its an old application using version "v1.4.2".I cannot upgrade it because at almost places .live is used

Comment: Ok i understand, i have modified my code with live. Use this code as it is, if it works than fine else please post the error, 
please check may be it helps you,